# Stuck on basics: How to prove that {subst($\alpha$,s)} is well defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

So I feel like this is a really basic point that I'm missing and I can't really manage to prove that:
So I have a substitution function $s: Var \rightarrow  WFF$ and a subst function:
$WFF \times WFF^{Var} \rightarrow (Symb \cup Var)$
I'm pretty sure it's a well known function so I'm not writing it's inductive definition.

I need to prove that for every $s$ and $\alpha$ exits a single $\beta$ s.t $subst(\alpha,s) = \beta$
I know i need to prove first that it exists and than that's it's uniqe.
But i'm not sure how, I think my main problem with this is that it's defined inductively.

Comment: If it's defined recursively, an inductive proof is often the way to go.

Comment: Can you please expand?

Comment: You can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951074/is-replacing-y-by-x-formally-a-valid-substitution-in-the-formula-forall-x) some examples of the *recursive* definition of *substitution* of a *term* into a *formula*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

First of all, we need the *recursive* definition of *substitution* into a *term*. See

- Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA60) (5th ed - 2013), page 60 :

> **Definition 3.3.9** Let $s, t$ be terms, then $s[t/x]$ is defined by:
>
> > *(i)* $y[t/x] := y$ if $y \ne x$ and $y[t/x] := t$ if $y = x$
> >
> > $\ \ \ \ \ c[t/x] := c$
> >
> > *(ii)* $f(t_1,\ldots, t_p)[t/x] := f(t_1[t/x],\ldots, t_p[t/x])$.

Then we use it in the definition of *substitution* into a *formula*; the relevant clauses are :

> **Definition 3.3.10** $\varphi[t/x]$ is defined by:
>
> > *(i)* [...] $P(t_1,\ldots, t_p)[t/x] := P(t_1[t/x],\ldots, t_p[t/x])$,
> >
> > $\ \ \ \ (t_1 = t_2)[t/x] := t_1[t/x] = t_2[t/x]$, for *atomic* formulae
> >
> > *(ii)* $(\varphi \square \psi)[t/x] := \varphi[t/x] \square \psi[t/x]$, where $\square$ stands for the usual binary *connectives* : $\land, \lor, \rightarrow$
> >
> > $\ \ \ \ (\lnot \varphi)[t/x] := \lnot \varphi [t/x]$
> >
> > *(iii)* $(∀y \varphi)[t/x] := ∀y(\varphi)[t/x]$ if $x \ne y$, $∀y \varphi$, if $x = y$.

---

With this "machinery" in place, what is the function *subst* ?

Here we need the details about your function $s$ ...

Without them, we can consider each *term* $\tau$ as a *function* $\tau : Var \to Term$, defined according to **Def.3.3.9** above, i.e. $\tau(x)= \sigma[\tau/x]$.

Having $\tau$, we can use it in the definition of $subst$ according to **Def.3.3.10** above.

If $\alpha$ is *atomic*, i.e. $\alpha := P(t_1,\ldots, t_p)$, then $\beta := subst(\alpha, \tau) := P(t_1[\tau/x],\ldots, t_p[\tau/x])$, and the same for $\alpha := (t_1 = t_2)$, with $\beta := (t_1[\tau/x] = t_2[\tau/x])$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it from here.