# Definition of substitution in FOL formulas

Tags: logic, definition, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Can someone please confirm that the following definition of substitution of terms in FOL formulas is correct and complete.

**For any formula $\phi$, the formula $\phi[t/x]$ is the formula $\phi$ with all occurrences of the term $x$ replaced with the term $t$, with the following conditions:**

- **$x$ must be free in $\phi$**
- **The term $t$ must be chosen so that any variables within $t$ do not become bound by any quantifier within $\phi$**

Is this sufficiently precise, and are there any other conditions/restrictions?

Comment: Perhaps a better way is a two-steps approach: (i) define the opeartion of *substitution*; (ii) define the poperty of "being free for" (os *substitutable*). See the post: [is-replacing-y-by-x-formally-a-valid-substitution-in-the-formula-forall-x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951074/is-replacing-y-by-x-formally-a-valid-substitution-in-the-formula-forall-x)

Comment: I agree that this isn't the most formal definition of substitution, but I want to avoid being too formal in a written piece introducing FOL to students.  I guess what I want to know is if there is anything misleading, absent, or inaccurate about the definition above?

Comment: Possible problem: without considering *occurrences*, you cannot subst $t$ in place of $x$ into e.g. $x=0 \to \forall x (x=0)$, because $x$ is bound (it has both free and bound occurrences).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I realise now that my definition may be confusing.  I think you have read this as no substitution can occur in $\phi$ if *any* $x$ is bound, whereas what I meant to convey is: substitute those $x$ that are free, and do not touch any others.  That is, the first condition should occur on a case by case basis on the variables $x$ within $\phi$.  The second condition is a "global" condition.

Comment: Requiring that $x$ _must_ occur free in $\phi$ seems to create more problems than it solves -- for example you now can't define that $(\varphi\to\psi)[t/x]$ is $\varphi[t/x]\to \psi[t/x]$ but need three different cases depending on whether $x$ is free in $\varphi$ or $\psi$ or both.

Comment: Also I would urge you to use a notation such as $\phi[x\mapsto t]$ instead, so the reader doesn't need to spend energy remembering a convention for what goes on which side of the slash in the case that $t$ is a variable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I think my definition is being misinterpreted.  What I mean is that an instance of a variable is replaceable by substitution only if it is free.  It doesn't require $x$ to be free in all occurrences within the formula.  As I said to Mauro, I accept that the definition above is probably not very well worded.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I also dislike the notation, but it is the notation used in the textbooks I use.  I have not actually seen the notation that you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two bullets are a separate issue from substitution. You can substitute any term for any variable in any formula (although only free occurrences will change).  The restrictions in the two bullets come from various inference rules, where only certain substitutions are acceptable.

Consider:

- $\phi_1 \equiv x = y$
- $\phi_2 \equiv x = 0 \to (\forall x)[x = 0]$ as mentioned by Mauro Allegranza in the comments

Then:

- $\phi_1[y/x] \equiv y = y$
- $\phi_2[y/x] \equiv y = 0 \to (\forall x)[x = 0]$

The simplest definition is just "$\phi[t/x]$ is the result of replacing every free occurrence of $x$ in $\phi$ with $t$. An occurrence of $x$ is a free occurrence if it does not appear in the scope of a quantifier $(\forall x)$ or $(\exists x)$."

Comment: Yes, this is what I intended by my definition, but I see why it may not be clear.  I guess my definition should read algorithmically as something like:  For each variable $x$ in $\phi$, {if ($x$ is free): {replace with $t$; if(a variable within $t$ becomes bound){error(illegal substitution)}}, else {do nothing}}

Comment: After re-reading, are you saying that substitution *does not* require the restriction in the second bullet point, but rather is a restriction on certain inference rules (such as UG)?

Comment: @esotechnica: yes, exactly - the substitution itself can be made if we only care about blindly making substitutions, but in order to prove that various inference rules are sound we need to consider a more limited collection of substitutions.

Comment: One other question, if you don't mind indulging me...  Is there any situation where we would want to 'blindly' perform a substitution which does not heed the condition as stated in the second point?  I can't conceive a situation where this would be desirable.

Comment: If we have a formula $(\forall x)\phi(x)$ and we want to substitute a term $t$ for $x$, this can be done without worrying whether any variable from $t$ already appears in the formula. It is really just a couple inference rules where the special conditions have to be checked.

Comment: Is it just the $\forall E$ and $\exists I$ rules where this condition needs to be checked?  This appears to be what the textbook I'm using is saying...

Comment: Yes, those are the most common two, if I understand your notation. There are many differences between book, and I can't remember if there are some other less common places where the substitutions are limited. The example in my previous comment is what I would call $\forall$ elimination